# MySQLi Delete statement doesn't delete

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

So I want to make a schedule, where people can check themselves in and if you have a certain rank in my system, you can check them out. The checking in part works, but, when I want to check out people using a  delete statement, they aren't deleted.

The code that I delete rows with:

```
public function roosterUit()
    {
        $dag = $_POST['dag'];
        $tijd = $_POST['uur'];
        $query = $this->db->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM ht_rooster WHERE dag = ? AND tijd = ?;");
        $query->bind_param('ss', $dag, $tijd);
        $query->execute();
        $query->close();
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with this function? I did a `var_dump` on `$query`, but it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: remove the `;` from your query.

Comment: why? it doesn't hurt to have the semicolon.

Comment: try adding something like this: if (!$query->execute()) 
        echo "there was an error:  (" . $query->errno . ") " . $query->error; exit; my initial thought is either 1) there isn't a row with the dag and tijd combination you're trying to delete, or 2) one of those fields isn't a string, but rather an int

Comment: @JeffHawthorne There is no error being shown, the row needs to exist, because the 'check out' button only shows when there is, and in my DB both `dag` and `tijd` are defined as a `VARCHAR`, not as an int, thats one of the reasons that I find it weird.

Comment: @RobinvandenBerg if you have a sql editor like phpmyadmin or mysql workbench, try pasting your query in there, replace the ? with the actual values and see if it works. once you verify that the query and data are indeed correct, then the problem is the connection. does the database account have delete permission, or is it read/write only?

Comment: @JeffHawthorne I tried that, and it worked, the DB account I'm using is the default root account that comes with XAMPP. I believe that the root account has no restrictions...

Comment: the only other things i can think of then is that either there's a typo, or you're not actually calling the function anywhere

Comment: @JeffHawthorne After checking, 3 times, no typo's, still, thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
   $query = $this->db->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM ht_rooster WHERE dag = ? AND tijd = ?;");
```

to

```
  $query = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM ht_rooster WHERE dag = ? AND tijd = ?;");
```

assuming that your connection.

```
  $conn = new mysqli("******", "*****", "*****", "*******");
```